# Keep getting corrupted file after downloading from Salesforce

Tags: python, rest, salesforce

I have pretty much reached the end of the code. Everything works except downloaded attachment is corrupted. It downloads the file, but when I try to open. It gives error saying file is damaged. I am probably not downloading correctly in the below line. The issue is pretty much in the last 4 lines somewhere.

Is this correct way to download the file?

donwloadAttachment= DOMAIN + attachment_url

```
def query(soql_query):
    
    #soql_query = 'SELECT name FROM Attachment'
    endpoint = '/services/data/v58.0/query/'
    records = []
    response = requests.get(DOMAIN + endpoint, headers=headers, params={'q': soql_query})
    data = response.json()
    df_records = pd.DataFrame(response)
    while not response.json()['done']:
        response = requests.get(DOMAIN + endpoint + response.json()['nextRecordsUrl'], headers=headers)
        records.extend(response.json()('records'))
    return {'record_size': total_size, 'records': records}

records = query('SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Parent.Type =\'Intake_Incident_Event__c\' AND ParentId in( SELECT Id FROM Intake_Incident_Event__c WHERE Incident_Date__c < 2018-12-31) LIMIT 1')
#print(records['record_size'])
df = pd.DataFrame(records['records'])

folder_path = "C:/Users/someguy/Desktop/Attachment Sandbox"

for row in df.iterrows():
    record_id = row[1]['ParentId']
    file_name = row[1]['Name']
    attachment_url = row[1]['Body']
    #print(attachment_url) #/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/Attachment/id/Body
    
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_path, record_id)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder_path, record_id))
    donwloadAttachment= DOMAIN + attachment_url

    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, record_id, file_name), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(donwloadAttachment.encode())
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import requests, io, os, datetime

sf = Salesforce(username= "your_Salesforce_user_name"
            ,password= "your_Salesforce_password"
            ,security_token= "your_Salesforce_security_token")

sid=sf.session_id

response = requests.get("the_Salesforce_link_that_the_attachment_stores", headers = sf.headers, cookies = {'sid' : sid})

with open('C:\\temp\\file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```